# Not wake up after suspension

Tags: ubuntu, suspend, hibernate

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop Lenovo T400. I had been using it quite well until this week.

After suspending Ubuntu, whenever I lift the laptop lid (if the lid is closed), or press "Fn" key (if the lid is not closed), normally Ubuntu should wake up. But starting this week, I couldn't wake it up either way for twice after I carrie my lap in my  backpack  running to another place.

When the problem happens, the laptop light for battery is on, which is normal for suspended status (if it is turned off, there should be no light on). the laptop light for reading/writing from/to HDD is only about 1/4 of full lightness on, which I guess suggests it meets some difficulty of reading data from HDD for waking up?

Is this related to some recent update of Ubuntu 12.04? Or is it a signal of onset of failure of some hardware part? Or ...? Thanks!

---

Added:

As terdon suggested, I upload

- the log files `/var/log/pm-*` before and after the problem happens [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wwyycfx8pcnskr3/ndGUM8dY2Y/pmlog). (the files ending in `.1` in their file names are those when I suspended Ubuntu, the files without `.1` are those most recent log files. Note: after the problem happens, I restarted my Ubuntu, and successfully suspended and woke Ubuntu.
- The output of my hardware info output by `lshw` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/hw)

Comment: This happens every now and then on each of the three laptops (including my T440) that I've used extensively. If it's only happened twice I wouldn't worry about it. If you're still worried, check `/var/log/pm-*` logs and see if there'[s anything relevant on http://www.thinkwiki.org. Also, suspend issues are very often linked to your graphics card so adding some details on your hardware might be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks! (1) which command to run for providing relevant details? (2) What to look for in /var/log/pm-*?

Comment: 1) Just list your hardware, use `inxi -G` if you have it or simply tell us your graphics card and driver. 2) I don't know what to look for, just any error messages really.

Comment: inxi -G command not found.

Comment: OK, try [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/284635/85695) but really, any hardware info tool like `lshw` or `hwinfo` should tell you.

Comment: I upload the log files before and after the problem happens [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wwyycfx8pcnskr3/ndGUM8dY2Y/pmlog). (the files ending in `.1` in their file names are those when I suspended Ubuntu, the files without `.1` are those most recent log files. Note: after the problem happens, I restarted my Ubuntu, and successfully suspended and woke Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you sure your machine is not waking, it looks like it is (`/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume success`). It might be waking up but not displaying anything on screen, you might have an X issue. Do you hear the fan start or any other indication of life?

Comment: I must say that  after the problem happened, I restarted my Ubuntu, and successfully suspended and woke Ubuntu again. Did you look at the right log for the problem or for my later operations?  When the problem happened, the laptop light for reading/writing HDD is about 1/4 of full brightness on, which seems to suggest it met some difficulty of reading back the data from my HDD? (I also have my hardware information [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/hw)

Comment: That's not usually what the light means as far as I know. What you describe sounds more and more like an X issue. Seriously though, this kind of rare problem is best ignored cause it'e rarely important and very hard to debug from a distance. And yes, I checked both files. In both the last line is `resume suspend: success.`

Comment: by the way, I didn't here fan working when the problem happened, just light for battery is on, light for suspension went from on to off, and light for hdd is 1/4 brightness. Is there some short cut key to force X to restart/recover without restarting the OS?

Comment: Yes, but [Ubuntu disables it by default.](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-enable-ctrl-alt-backspace-in-ubuntu-jaunty.html)

Comment: @terdon: will restarting X close previous opened applications' windows?

Comment: Yes it will, sorry.

Comment: (1) What is it like if it is X's problem? My screen was completely dark as if the computer was turned off, and the only signals for the system was on were just those laptop lights I mentioned earlier. (2) What do you think about my hardware, esp. graphical card? Signs for failure?

Answer (score 4):

I have a Thinkpad T410 and was plagued by this issue for years. I was using Fedora 14 but noticed that certain applications would tend to cause this issue if I left them open when I attempted to have the laptop suspend via closing the lid. I would make sure to close these applications once I recognized the pattern.

I'll also note that since upgrading to Fedora 19 I've not had this issue come up a single time, so you might have some luck by simply migrating up to Ubuntu 13.10.

The main applications that would cause this?

- LibreOffice (any of the apps such  as Writer, Calc, etc.)
- SSH connections to remote systems
- Virt-Manager

I've always just kept Chrome open and that never seemed to cause any issues.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have such issue until this week. I didn't have any rarely-used applications opened when the problem happened. One thing to note is that I had about 200 tabs opened in Firefox, which hadn't been problem for years before, and I don't think it might be a problem, since my RAM still had about 5+GB free space.

Comment: Wow, LibreOffice was indeed causing the same problem for me! Thanks for your detective work ;) Do you know why this is, and how to fix it properly instead of just closing LibreOffice before closing my laptop lid?

Comment: I've moved up to newer versions of LibreOffice and it seems to have lessened since upgrading to 4.x versions, I'm currently at 4.1.6.2.